# How to create an asymmetric motion slider in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi guys how can I make an asymmetric motion slider in java? Can I use a thread?

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(speed, null);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (lim1 > progress) {
            speed = 20;
        } else if (lime2 > progress) {
            speed = 10;
        } else {
            speed = 5;
        }
        System.out.println(speed);
        progress++;
        setcircle();
        if (progress >= lim) {
            timer.stop();
        }

    }
});
timer.start();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? It's not clear what your question/problem is.

Comment: @Thomas i wanna make a slider which has asymmetric motion in java swing. check this link https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight

Comment: That looks like a matter of animation to me but more suited to toggle buttons than sliders. In any case you might want to look into the swing animation tutorials.

Comment: what do you mean with asymmetric motion slider exactly?

Comment: @Hector check the link i posted above

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Probably, you don't want a `JSlider`. I assume that you want a class/function that you can give a time (between 0 and 1), and it returns a position, and this function (time->position) should have the shape that can be seen in the given link. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed something like this to simulate the "simple harmonic motion" ([github repo](https://github.com/hcarrasc/SHM-simulator/)). To do this, I've use a `TimerTask()` class. You could use this two approaches:

```
long delay = 0;
long interval = 1000;

Timer temporizer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // update here you progress bar or another elements
    }
};

temporizer.schedule (task,delay,interval); //task will be excecuted each 1 second.
```

Parameters in schedule method are:

- `TimerTask task` object
- `long delay` (delay time in the first run expressed in milliseconds)
- `long interval` (time of each iteration of task expressed in milliseconds).

or a simple

```
while (true){
    // update here you progress bar or another elements
    try { 
        Thread.sleep(interval); 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {...}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Herctor what are the parameters for the first option?

Comment: I've eddited my answer adding the parameters description :)